Class MongoDB\Driver\Monitoring\CommandSubscriber was not found
I'm trying to install my Symfony application on my VPS. My app uses MongoDB for a noSQL db. When accessing the website, I get
Class "MongoDB\Driver\Monitoring\CommandSubscriber" not found while loading "Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\APM\StopwatchCommandLogger".
I installed mongodb with pecl
Added extension = mongodb in the php.ini
I cloned my repo
I ran composer update, then composer install -> No errors
I then tried to access my app and got the error message
Class "MongoDB\Driver\Monitoring\CommandSubscriber" not found while loading "Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\APM\StopwatchCommandLogger".
I'm using php 8.2, mongodb 1.18
phpinfo returns
MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.18.0
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libbson bundled version => 1.26.1
libmongoc bundled version => 1.26.1


The phpinfo output resembles the output of the php --ini command in the command line (CLI SAPI). Are you testing your app in a web environment (e.g., PHP-FPM SAPI)? I recommend verifying that the mongodb extension is enabled for the web SAPI if your app is web-based. Additionally, please share your composer.json and the exact shell commands used to install the dependencies. Providing a [mre] would be even more helpful.

I'm trying ot run the app on my vps that runs on ubuntu 22.04, and used nginx

What is the source of the MongoDB support => enabled output? Did you create a PHP file with contents similar to <?php phpinfo(); and open it using an HTTP request? I mean that there are different php.ini files for PHP-FPM (which is likely to be used in conjunction with Nginx) and CLI, and you might be modifying the CLI version instead of the PHP-FPM.

It's from <? php phpinfo() in cli, any idea on how to check if the .ini are not the same ?

On Ubuntu, it's typically something like /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/ (adjust according to your PHP version). The user is expected to create a file like 90-mongodb.ini inside of that directory, with the extension directive such as extension=mongodb.so

i followed your directions and created 20-mongodb.ini
``
root@srv:/etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d# cat 20-mongodb.ini
extension=mongodb.so
root@srv:/etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d# pwd
/etc/php/8.2/fpm/conf.d


After changing php.ini files you need to restart the php-fpm service, then check the phpinfo() by opening the index.php using an HTTP request (e.g. in a browser). (The URL depends on your nginx configuration.)

I think you just solved my problem dude ! Thanks a lot !

The phpinfo output MongoDB support => enabled resembles the output of the php --ini command or the phpinfo() function call in the command line interface (CLI SAPI). The phpinfo() function call in a web server environment (e.g. php-fpm, cgi, or apache2handler SAPIs), however, typically shows an output in HTML format.
Therefore, I think you are modifying a configuration file that is not used by the web server. You can find out which php.ini file is used by the web server by creating a PHP file with the following content:
<?php
phpinfo();

Then open this file in a web browser and search for the Loaded Configuration File directive. This directive shows the path to the php.ini file that is used by the web server. Modern Linux distributions often split configuration files, so you may need to check the directory under the 'Scan this dir for additional .ini files' directive as well. On Ubuntu, it's typically something like /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/ (adjust according to your PHP version). The user is expected to create a file like 90-mongodb.ini inside of that directory, with the extension directive such as extension=mongodb.so.
After changing the configuration file, you need to restart the SAPI service (such as the php-fpm service) to apply the changes.
